# fijar dos DIV logo y menú con bootstrap

Tags: css, menu

tengo un problema que no le estoy encontrando la vuelta hace ya un tiempo
Tengo el logo de una empresa que se muestra en un div arriba de todo y por debajo cargo el menu de la web
El problema es que necesito que estos dos queden estáticos siempre visibles y solo me queda el menu porque el div del logo al abrir está arriba pero al hacer scroll se va y queda solo el del menu

Esto es por la regla de bootstrap `sticky-top`

El problema es que al poner esto en los dos div me los superpone. Yo necesito que ambos  queden fijos arriba siempre. Es posible hacer eso ?

Dejo el código completo el body. El proyecto esta realizado integramente con bootstrap

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba Bootstrap v5.0</title>
    
     <!-- Bootstrap y Alert -->
        <link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-utilities.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="libs/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="container-fluid d-none d-md-block">
      <a href="#"><img class="mx-auto d-block p-1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" height="60px"></a>
   </div> 

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark borde-menu shadow-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">LOGO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
      
      
   <div style="height: 2000px;">Texto del cuerpo</div>


    <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
     

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es envolver al logo y al menú en un `<div>` contenedor y a ese darle la clase `sticky-top`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba Bootstrap v5.0</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap y Alert -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cabecera" class="sticky-top">
      <div id="logo" class="container-fluid d-none d-md-block">
        <a href="#"><img class="mx-auto d-block p-1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" height="60px"></a>
    </div> 
   
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark borde-menu shadow-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">LOGO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
    </div>
     
   <div style="height: 2000px;">Texto del cuerpo</div>
    <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
     

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución más simple es "encerrar" ambos divs en un contenedor padre y aplicar la clase sticky-top allí.

```
<div class="sticky-top">
    <!-- tu logo -->
    <!-- tu navbar -->
</div>
```

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando
https://codepen.io/marcelozarate/pen/qBpPJzm